# Problems reading GML file (not reprojected)

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to read a GML in openlayers 3.4.0 file with this code

```
var from = ol.proj.get("EPSG:4326");
var to = ol.proj.get("EPSG:3857");
var gml = new ol.source.StaticVector({
    format: new ol.format.GML2({dataProjection: from, 
                                featureProjection: to}),
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    url: 'test_4326.gml'
}); 
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: gml
});
var map;
function init(){
    map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [vectorLayer],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2
        })
    });
}
```

that works fine with KML or GeoJSON (changing ol.format and removing relative parameters) but not with GML file (also without parameters in ol.format.GML2), I did some try with different gml files but nothing is working. It seems that the coordinates are nor reprojected during the reading phase.
Which is the correct way to read a GMl file?

The test is at http://kili.aspix.it/ol/testGML.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this currently is to use a normal ol.source.Vector, fetch the data using XHR manually and do the parsing directly on the format so you can specify all the options to the readFeatures function. After that you'll add the features to the source. For example:

```js
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector()
});
var format = new ol.format.GML2();
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "gml.xml", true);
xmlhttp.onload = function() {
  var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
  var features = format.readFeatures(xmlDoc, {
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'
  });
  vector.getSource().addFeatures(features);
};
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: No longer works with OpenLayers 3.5.0
AssertionError: Assertion failed: objectStack is supposed to be an array of arrays